# The family of open intervals that do not contain $0$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $T$ be the collection of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ not containing $0$ union $\mathbb{R}$ i.e
$$T=\{(a,b)\subset\mathbb{\bar R}:0\notin(a,b)\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}$$

Then what is true about $T$?

$1.$Hausdorff

$2.$Compact

$3.$Connected

My try:It is not Hausdorff because for $0\neq1$ we can not find two disjoint open sets $U,V$ containing separately $0,1$.

About other two options I do not have any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Small question for clarity - do you mean $\cup \mathbf{R}$ or $\cup \{\mathbf{R}\}$?

Comment: U{R} sorry and thanks

Comment: Should $T$ include the set $(-\infty, -1)$? Your first line says it should, and your second line says it doesn't.

Comment: @MJD good point.My first is correct statement,ok I will edit this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean $T$ is the smallest topology containing these sets - $T$ itself is not for example closed under unions.

Here is a thought for 2:  How many open sets in your topology include the point $0$?  What might this imply about an open cover in this topology?

Comment: Only one open set {R} so it is compact???

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't had time to think about connectedness, but I hope you get it!  Yes, there is only one open set, $\mathbb{R}$ that includes $0$, so any open cover has to include $\mathbb{R}$ or else it isn't a cover because it doesn't "cover" $0$!  Therefore it has a super simple finite subcover, which is $\{\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: It is also connected.

Comment: That was what I thought from imagining it, but I wasn't sure yet!